# Error "The provided key element does not match the schema" without sort key

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a problem with a DynamoDB table.

I only have the partition key; when I request all the elements these are displayed correctly, while when I want to get only one element with specific id I get the following error:

***The provided key element does not match the schema***

Yet I only have the partition key (Primary Key). without the sort key.

This is the relative lambda function code:

```js
case "GET /fragments/{id}":
        body = await dynamo
          .get({
            TableName: "frammento",
            Key: {
              id: event.pathParameters.id
            }
            .promise();
           break;
          })
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: What is the schema and what exactly is `event.pathParameters.id`?

Comment: event.pathParameters.id is HTTP events can be configured to pass in path parameters to your lambda function, ie the fragment id. What do you mean what is the schema? because I have recently been using aws lambda

Comment: How did you define your table? Primary key? Sort key?

Comment: I defined it Primary key

Comment: I am thinking of one thing. As I had previously created another table with the same name which contained both primary key (id) and sort key (id_a), I made a backup of this table before deleting it. Then I created a new table with the same name but only with id primary key. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Are you using the document client or the low level client?

Comment: what do you mean? because I'm just following this tutorial on this site: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/it_it/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-dynamo-db.html